# Multiple Releases to Different audiences - Atlassian / Jira / Confluence

Tags: svn, jira, confluence

We are managing a script library. Scripts are created in SCRUM methodology as tasks / issues and are committed to SVN repo linked to our Atlassian / Jira.

Lets assume it looks like this:

```
//Script Lib:

Issue 1 -> linked source file: "Script 1"
Issue 2 -> linked source file: "Script 2"
Issue 3 -> linked source file: "Script 3"
```

In addition say we have 3 target audiences that we would like to release the scripts to and following mappings:

```
Target Audience 1 needs -> Script 1, Script 2
Target Audience 2 needs -> Script 2 
Target Audience 3 needs -> Script 1, Script 3
```

I wanted somehow to utilize release system in Atlassian / JIRA, so that I could have releases containing these scripts for specific audiences.

E.g.

```
Target Audience 1 -> Releases starting with 1.0.0 (containing Script 1, Script 2)
Target Audience 2 -> Releases starting with 2.0.0 (containing Script 2)
Target Audience 3 -> Releases starting with 3.0.0 (containing Script 1, Script 3)
```

Basically I want to be able to release same issues several times or have a similar behavior achieved, so that I can create tagged releases targeting different audiences

Comment: What about using JIRA components? You can create components and assign them to issues. Also I don't understand what you mean by linking issues with source files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't associate an Issue with more than one Version or Release. However, you could create use linked issues to allow to create release packages. You would have a primary Issue that you use in your Scrum to track progress until the Script is complete. For each customer who is going to receive that script, you would create a linked issue that is assigned to the customer's release. This would allow you to build release packages associated with the specific recipient.